STS 4.22.1 - Maven Remote Catalogue is not working
STS 4.22.1 release remote catalogue  configuration gives "Archetype Catalog is empty" error, but the same catalog url is working in STS 4.8.1 release. Is there any open issue with latest sts version?

Most likely a question related to the maven integration in Eclipse, to added those tags. Probably worth to tr this with plain vanilla Eclipse installs to see how this behaves without the Spring-related extensions

This is related to maven archetype integration with STS. It looks like the latest version(4.22.1) of STS has issues with maven catalog configuration.  I have tried STS 4.15.1, and it works.

Can you try the same with a plain vanilla Eclipse 2024-06 Java package to see if that works for you?
